# How do I get conjure-up to work properly?

Tags: software-installation, snap, conjure-up

I am running Ubuntu 16 via AWS.  As root I ran this command to install conjure-up:

```
snap install conjure-up --classic
```

I then ran this command:

```
conjure-up
```

I get this error:

```
dropping privs did not work
```

I have checked logs to no avail.  I have rebooted, but the problem persists.  How do I use conjure-up on Ubuntu?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what version of snap? Use ```snap version``` to find out and paste please. I just tested this on Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked. ```$ snap version
snap    2.22.7
snapd   2.22.7
series  16
ubuntu  16.04
kernel  4.8.0-41-generic
``` is what I'm running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing, since you didn't include `sudo` before the install command, that you are running these as root.  However, `conjure-up` is intended to be run as a regular user, not as root.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same thing with a fresh install of 16.04 and 16.10 
effects conjure-up and juju.  Seems like something with the LXD service running two instances. I suggest try to remove both installs of lxd and install one via snap.

Good Luck and let me know if you succeed

Matee